# Numpy: How to create a grid-like array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create an array which represent X-Y panel (-50, 50). That is:
`[[-50, -50], [-49,-50],[-48,-50]....[50,50]]`, which is at length 101*101.

Clearly, I can generate through a `double loop from (-50,50)`. I'm wondering the `prefered` way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`numpy.meshgrid` is obviously the clearest way to me (as @benbo has mentioned), you need one more step to `ravel` or `flatten` the 2D grid array:

```
In [131]: import numpy as np
     ...: x=np.linspace(-2, 2, 5)
     ...: y=np.linspace(-2, 2, 5)
     ...: xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y)
     ...: coords=np.array((xx.ravel(), yy.ravel())).T

In [132]: coords
Out[132]: 
array([[-2., -2.],
       [-1., -2.],
       [ 0., -2.],
       [ 1., -2.],
       [ 2., -2.],
       [-2., -1.],
       ......
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])

In [133]:
```

Or as @John mentioned, shorten your code with `np.c_` to skip the transpose:

```
coords=np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
```

To benchmark:

```
In [156]: %timeit coords=np.array((xx.ravel(), yy.ravel())).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 µs per loop

In [157]: %timeit coords=np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()] #not as efficient as ↑
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it IMO. You can also use np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()] and skip the transpose.

Comment: interesting -- I wouldn't have expected the `np.array` way to be faster. Always check with `%timeit`!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
In [15]: import numpy as np

In [16]: a = np.arange(-3,4)

In [17]: a1 = np.tile(a, (7,1))

In [18]: np.dstack((a1, a1.T)).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Result:

```
array([[-3, -3],
       [-2, -3],
       [-1, -3],
       [ 0, -3],
       [ 1, -3],
        ....
       [-1,  3],
       [ 0,  3],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you want your output to look like. Does this work for you?

```
import numpy as np
a=np.linspace(-2, 2, 5)
b=np.linspace(-2, 2, 5)
c,d=np.meshgrid(a,b)
c+d
>>> array([[-4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.],
   [-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.],
   [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
   [-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]])
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood when you said grid-like

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array( zip(range(-50,51), [-50] * 50 + [50] * 51) )
array([[-50, -50],
       [-49, -50],
       [-48, -50],
       .
       .
       .
       [ 48,  50],
       [ 49,  50],
       [ 50,  50]])
```

Answer (score 0):

it maybe looks like this:

```
In [1]: coords = np.array([[_v, _v] for _v in range(-50, 51)])

In [2]: coords
Out[22]: 
array([[-50, -50],
       [-49, -49],
       [-48, -48],
       ...
       ...
       ...
       [ 48,  48],
       [ 49,  49],
       [ 50,  50]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers!  And here's another, based on [`numpy.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```
In [1458]: low = -50

In [1459]: high = 51

In [1460]: ndim = 2

In [1461]: coords = (np.indices((high-low,)*ndim) + low)[::-1].reshape(ndim, -1).T

In [1462]: coords
Out[1462]: 
array([[-50, -50],
       [-49, -50],
       [-48, -50],
       ..., 
       [ 48,  50],
       [ 49,  50],
       [ 50,  50]])
```

If it is not essential that the first coordinate varies the fastest, the reordering achieved by `[::-1]` can be removed:

```
In [1463]: coords = (np.indices((high-low,)*ndim) + low).reshape(ndim, -1).T

In [1464]: coords
Out[1464]: 
array([[-50, -50],
       [-50, -49],
       [-50, -48],
       ..., 
       [ 50,  48],
       [ 50,  49],
       [ 50,  50]])
```

The use of `ndim` provides a gratuitous feature; it allows for generating a similar array in higher dimensions:

```
In [1465]: ndim = 3

In [1466]: coords = (np.indices((high-low,)*ndim) + low)[::-1].reshape(ndim, -1).T

In [1467]: coords
Out[1467]: 
array([[-50, -50, -50],
       [-49, -50, -50],
       [-48, -50, -50],
       ..., 
       [ 48,  50,  50],
       [ 49,  50,  50],
       [ 50,  50,  50]])
```